# 'Gotham Book' font-family not working in Safari browser and IPhone devices

Tags: css, fonts, safari, font-face

In my project I need to use Gotham Book font-family and I am using following code:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'Gotham Book';
            src: 
                url('assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.eot'),
                url('assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.woff') format('woff'),
                url('assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

If perfectly works in android devices and other browsers except safari browser.
Please suggest what is the wrong in my code.

What causing this issue?

I also tried with Gotham Book svg import, but did not worked for me.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how the font is looking in Safari and iphone?

Comment: Font is not loading. It shows nothing. If i inspect the code and changed the font-family name it working fine on safari.

Comment: If you are adding the font in a live site as HTTPS, then add full path of the font assets URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the working Solution
CSS :

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: "gotham";
  src: url('ff/Gotham-Book.woff') format('woff'),
       url('ff/Gotham-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('ff/Gotham-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

and Please replace your existing font by downloading font from below URl:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pbdpXbPRCJC6Qi-QpNGt7WbLuwtwDRUW

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the whole URL of the font assets.

**CSS:-**

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'Gotham Book';
            src: 
                url('https://www.example.com/assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.eot'),
                url('https://www.example.com/assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('https://www.example.com/assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('https://www.example.com/assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.woff') format('woff'),
                url('https://www.example.com/assets/fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhLP. Will check with this