# 'Gotham Bold' font-family is not working in Safari browser

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

In my current work, I need to use the Gotham Bold font-family.
This is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377981/gotham-book-font-family-not-working-in-safari-browser-and-iphone-devices).

I have downloaded the **.woff** font format for Gotham Bold from [here](https://github.com/jbuck/book-of-judith/blob/master/public/fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff) and the **.woff2** from [here](https://github.com/dagvonkr/hof2/blob/master/public/GOTHAM-BOLD.woff2)

Currently I have tried:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GothamBold;
    src:    url(../fonts/GothamBold.ttf) format('truetype')
            url(../fonts/GOTHAM-BOLD.woff) format('woff'),
            url(../fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

It is quite possible that I have the incorrect files for .woff and .woff2, as the actual font doesn't load on Safari. Where do I get the correct version of these files?

Comment: What font weight(s) does the font file contain?

Comment: These two are single files, I analyzed the Gotham-Bold.woff with the help of [this](https://fontdrop.info/) and it has got a bold font weight.

Comment: And did you set the font-weight in the CSS?